# How I can use C++ STL Sort for sorting array of object with inheritance

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, sorting, stl

Im trying to sort an array of objects by one of their attributes using c++ STL `sort()` but I always get an error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'bool sortByArea(const Shape*, const Shape*)':
main.cpp:54:22: error: passing 'const Shape' as 'this' argument of 'double Shape::getArea()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  return lhs->getArea() < rhs->getArea();
                      ^
main.cpp:54:39: error: passing 'const Shape' as 'this' argument of 'double Shape::getArea()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  return lhs->getArea() < rhs->getArea();
```

Here is my code:

Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"

Shape::Shape(){
    width=0;
    height=0;
    area=0;
    perimeter=0;
}

Shape::Shape(double newwidth, double newheight, double newarea, double newperimeter){
    width=newwidth;
    height=newheight;
    area=newarea;
    perimeter=newperimeter;
}

Shape::~Shape(){

}

double Shape::getWidth(){
    return width;
}

double Shape::getHeight(){
    return height;
}

double Shape::getArea(){
    return area;
}

double Shape::getPerimeter(){
    return perimeter;
}

double Shape::calArea(){
    return 0;
}

double Shape::calPerimeter(){
    return 0;
}
```

Circle.cpp

```
#include "Circle.h"
#include <cmath>
#define PI 3.141592654

Circle::Circle(){
    width = height = 0;
    area=0; perimeter=0;
}

Circle::Circle(double newradius){
    width = height = newradius;
    area = calArea(); perimeter = calPerimeter();
}

Circle::~Circle(){

}

double Circle::calArea(){
    return (pow(width,2)*PI);
}

double Circle::calPerimeter(){
    return (width * PI * 2);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Square.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
const int size = 200;
int cshape = 0; int rshape = 0; int sshape = 0;

void input_circle(Shape* mshape){
    ifstream file;
    int i;
    double r;
    file.open("circle.txt");
    while (file >> r){
        Circle crl(r);
        mshape[cshape]=crl;
        cshape++;
    }
    file.close();
}

bool sortByArea(const Shape * lhs, const Shape * rhs) { 
    return lhs->getArea() < rhs->getArea(); 
}


int main(){
    Shape* shapecir;
    shapecir = new (nothrow) Circle[size]();
    input_circle(shapecir);
    int i;
    cout << "Circle" << endl;
    sort(shapecir,shapecir+size,sortByArea);
    for (i=0;i<cshape;i++)
        cout << shapecir[i].getArea() << " " << shapecir[i].getPerimeter() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to find something on the internet but I can't find anything that can help.

Comment: "some error". What error specifically?

Comment: Please copy/paste ... *THE EXACT ERROR*!  Also: why not `Shape* shapecir = new Circle();`?

Comment: Could you reduce your file full of circles to the [smallest version that reproduces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that? Or better still, hard-code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to have tested these functions as you wrote them. The problem is here:

```
double Shape::getArea(){
    return area;
}

bool sortByArea(const Shape * lhs, const Shape * rhs) { 
    return lhs->getArea() < rhs->getArea(); 
}
```

You correctly gave `sortByArea` const pointer arguments, but neglected to make `getArea` a const function. The compiler is telling you that you are commanding that the code perform an operation that might change the shapes, after you forbade that they be changed.

Comment: I tried to erase the const but I still got many error.
maybe you can help me to explain what I must do to sort shapecir based on area.

Comment: @Alvin: Make `getArea` const; test that in isolation. Once it works, test `sortByArea` in isolation. Once that works, try sorting an array with it.

Comment: Declare it like this: `double Shape::getArea() const`. And in the class declaration: `double getArea() const;`

Comment: i have tried it, it resolve that error i mention before but now i got many error about the sort();

Comment: @Alvin: *Did... you... test... `sortByArea`... in... isolation?*

Comment: @Beta okay, i solved it, I change to this
`bool sortByArea(Shape lhs, Shape rhs) { 
 return lhs.getArea() < rhs.getArea(); 
}`
and 
`sort(shapecir,shapecir+cshape,sortByArea);`

Comment: @alvin look up "slicing".